# Query about B1 application from India

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals

I had applied for US B1 visa from China and got refusal. Now I am applying again US B1/B2 visa from India. 
Which option should I select "Yes or No" for below question.

Have you ever been denied or refused a visa or entry to any country?

Comment: You answer "Yes", of course. By what possible logic could it be correct to answer "No"?

Comment: No reason to close this Q, come on, it is clear as it can be, look to the answer, it's useful as well. Voting to leave open.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you should answer "Yes!" You have been denied a visa before; that was literally the first thing you told us about yourself here.

The US officials aren't stupid. They have your previous application records available and know that you were refused before. If you answer "No," they will rightly conclude you have given a false statement on your application, and then you will have much bigger problems. Any lies on a visa application greatly hurt your credibility and can make it far harder to get a visa in the future.

Comment: Your 1st paragraph is fine, but not the second. The refusal was by China: do the Chinese really share visa data with the US? I have no idea but am somewhat sceptical.

Comment: @simonatrcl He applied for a US visa in China (went to a US consulate inside of China) and was refused. Now he wants to apply for a US visa in India (going to a US consulate inside of India). The US officials in China certainly share visa data with the US officials in India. China does not issue B1 visas.